Jhipster's migrate blueprint from 7.8.1 to 7.9.4 is not upgrading the angular version to 14.x
Going through all the documentation, when trying to upgrade my jhipster project that is on 7.8.1, using the jhipster-migrate --verbose program, it gets to the target branch and the package.json is showing 7.9.4 for the generator, but the angular versions are all still 13.x which is the same as 7.8.1. I am taking this slow as to not wanting to jump to 8.x yet on jhipster. I tried this with a sample project and my actual JDL file and it worked, although not easy but still worked. Any tips or pointers for fixing this? I have tried it too many times to count. I even tried manually and it doesn't work. Could there be something bugged in my repo?
Tried to use the jhipster-migrate blueprint multiple times. Tried deleting the node_modules/generator-jhipster half way through the migrate since it asks when to start the target verseion. Deleted it to just be sure it uses the right version. Tried uninstalling generators globally and also deleting node_modules and starting on fresh npm install. Same result.

Can you please enter an issue for this in the Migrate blueprint's repo? https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-migrate

Done. Really hope I can get some solution to this. Been working on upgrading the app for a month all because I need to associate User's with entities and it was bugged in 7.8.1
